# What's the deal with the CRT SECURE warnings/errors on visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I encountered this issue a dozen, if not a million times already: I compile a c++ program on visual studio and get a dozen, if not a million warnings and/or errors suggesting that I am doing something very dangerous and that there is no way my compiler will let me do that. the warnings/errors tell me that I am using a deprecated function and that I should consider using some other safer function that may or may not do the same thing as this one, but I have no idea what this one does in the first place since I did not write it.

After some research (I do it everytime, I am not a quick learner) I  find out I am not the first one facing this particular problem, and I can coerce my compiler to work with this program with the proper macro definition (for the future readers who don't care about my question but want to compile their program, you have to define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE, don't you ever dare following visual studio's advice and using the allegedly *safe* function).

I have often read in the manual or on this very website, along with the answer, the fact that I should not do that if I don't know precisely what I am doing.

I must confess: I have no idea what I am doing, and I would be very grateful if someone would accept to explain it to me.

So here are my questions:

- What are those functions that are unsafe? Why do they exist in the first place?
- What is unsafe about them?
- Why are they so often found in perfectly honourable libraries?
- I have come to the understanding that there is no safe and portable alternative to those functions: why is it so? How about we have some people think about it and try to define a way to do it, and everyone would accept to do it that way, and we would call it standard maybe?

Comment: In case you haven't already read it: [Security Features in the CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx).

Comment: `Why are they so often found in perfectly honourable libraries?` because the standard c does not have the Microsoft proprietary versions.

Comment: Microsoft is not that keen to help anybody exploit the buffer overflow and handle recycle attack vectors that are built into the standard C library.  You've been warned, you can claim your right to expose these security weaknesses in your program with a simple macro.

Answer (score -1):

To tackle your questions in order:

- They exist in the first place because the standard wrote them in such a way. Standards authors are human so don't think of everything and this left some security weaknesses in the C API. You can find a list of these deprecated functions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235384.aspx.
- Many of the functions are unsafe as they allow such things as buffer overruns to occur but other security vulnerabilities may be exposed depending on the function.
- Honourable libraries generally try for some cross platform compatibility so I suspect will try to stick to stand C rather than using compiler specific functions and extensions.
- The "perfect" standard will probably never exist as in my first point :) Some of the C API problems can be avoided using C++ but that's a big hammer to crack a small nut and brings security vulnerabilities of its own.

Comment: -0.5 for the standard authors; the modern security notion simply wasn't relevant in the context where C was developed. The OS took care of security there. -0.5 for the idea that C++ brings new security vulnerabilities; most fundamental issues are inherited from C. Microsoft has done good work on their secure C++ libraries which are secured against buffer overflows using standard interfaces.

Comment: In response: My comment on standards authors is exactly what you say They can't think of everything and no API can't be completely future proof. And, sorry, C++ does bring new security vulnerabilities :(